# Watermark in Magento Products

Tags: magento

Need to show a watermark in each magento products so that nobody can copy the products images. Any suggestions what we can do on `view.phtml` page and on `list.phtml` page?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set watermark image via admin backend.
Hope this link will help you.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/configuration-general-design-product-image-watermarks/

Comment: more details in http://go.magento.com/support/kb/entry/name/using-product-image-watermarks/

Comment: Did not able to see on product page, any comments ?